# make ChoiceField() take any value

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm using the forms framework and I'm using a but of javascript magic to inject some values on the fly into a select box (the values of this select box relies on a value form another).

Basically you have Team and Players. You need to define a player, but the players data comes from a Team.

In my form class i have

```
team = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Team.objects.all()
player = forms.ChoiceField()
```

In the front end when the user selects a team from the select box, the (empty) players boxes gets correctly updated with new data. However when i hit submit, the player select box throws a error `Select a valid choice. 2 is not one of the available choices.` 2 IS a valid choice however.

Is there any way around this? Can i make the ChoiceField() take any value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordered by complexity DESC:

1. Prepopulate it with all possible choices. For example, if you select player's id, it will be `choices = Player.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)`
2. Define it as `CharField`, but render it manually in template as select box.
3. Don't define it in form, but pass it's value to form's constructor (which you need to override to process this value.)

Comment: Number 2 seems the best solution. No need to load data i don't need, and will pick up any value.

Comment: I decided this solution was the best, using a Charfield().

Comment: @dotty As I understand it isn't generated by your form, isn't validated by your form and isn't processed by your form. Are you sure you want it to be the part of your form?

Comment: I'll validate it with my view, after form.is_valid() is called, it'll check to see if the CharField() is an integer. If it isn't I'll throw an error.

Comment: @dotty But why do you need it in form if it has no affect of field's appearance, validation or further processing?

Comment: But the value from the dynamic `ChoiceField` is being saved to a record. Both Team and Player are being saved. So i need this value.

Comment: @dotty Override `.save()` method as you like.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the field as a CharField with forms.Select as the widget. That way the field is rendered as an empty select element and will accept any value.

```
player = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select)
```

this is useful if you're using Select2 and loading values via ajax.

Comment: This is a good Solution to use Django with Select2 Ajax option. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own ChoiceField, say DynamicChoiceField that extends from ChoiceField. You can then override the "clean" method to not do any validation as it would do with a regular ChoiceField.

```
class DynamicChoiceField(forms.ChoiceField):     
    def clean(self, value):
        // Do whatever validation needs to happen
```

In the form, you could use DynamicChoiceField instead of ChoiceField

Comment: Would i use this like `forms.DynamicChoiceField()`?

Comment: You could declare DynamicChoiceField in say, myfields.py and import it as you would import any other python module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data parameter passed to init function to update choices dynamically.

```
class PlayerTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    team = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Team.objects.all()
    player = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [])
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerTeamModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('data'): # When form is submitted
            # prefix for formsets
            prefix = kwargs.get('prefix') + '-' if kwargs.get('prefix') else ''
            player = Player.objects.get(
                pk = kwargs.get('data').get(prefix + 'player')
            )
            self.fields['player'].choices = [[
                player.pk, player.name
            ]]
        else:
            self.fields['player'].choices = [[
                self.instance.player_id, self.instance.player.name
            ]]
```